# Raw Text as a Substitute for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, mysqli

I am renting a server which does not support MySQL. An upgrade would be significantly expensive.

So for the moment, I am trying to cope with using raw text.

So here is a database syntax I am thinking about:

- {first line} metadata (id, name, date, number of rows, number of columns, etc.)
- {second line} column headers
- {rest of lines} column data, separated by a deliminator

Example (using `*` as a deliminator):

```
rmC2xA7f*Users*1436703535*3*5
id*first*last*email*password
d29JHVca*Example*User*example.user@example.com*examplepassword123
tGpy3CM6*Foo*Bar*foo.bar@foobar.com*foobarpassword456
PdQMDHsK*Bla*Bla*bla.bla@bla.com*blablapassword789
```

I would then create a PHP library for manipulating this text. I know that it wouldn't be as efficient, scalable or fast a MySQL, but would this be an acceptable substitute for a small, personal website?

Are there any issues with it, or any way I could improve it? I'll probably change the `*` to something else if you're thinking that.

Also, comment if this question should be on a different network...
Thanks :).

Comment: For a self-contained, serverless, SQL database engine, consider using [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Does your plan support SQLIte? That would be better than a flat file mess

Comment: I'm actually not sure, @RiggsFolly. I will look into it. I really would prefer to use something like that over a raw text format. Thanks for the reference :).

Comment: You can search the output of [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) for the word `SQLite` to see if your php installation supports it. If it does, you should use it instead of writing your own implementation.

Comment: Yes, I will look at that asap. I hope it does @Asaph.

Comment: Incidentally, with the exception the first line (which you can store elsewhere if you must), your proposed format is reminiscent of the CSV file format with a custom delimiter. PHP has a host of built-in functions for reading/writing CSV files including support for custom delimiters. So don't write your own CSV parser either.

Comment: Oh okay, that's interesting @Asaph.

Comment: @Asaph, MySQL is in the phpinfo() callback, so maybe it has been somehow disabled?

Comment: If not SQLlite, I wouldn't recommend the CSV route. JSON or XML will be much easier to maintain. But how will you manage normalcy or unions or joins?

Comment: @eggmatters I'm actually not sure what you mean by normalcy, unions and joins in this context.

Comment: @Mirabilis MySQL support and SQLite support can coexist peacefully. If the word "SQLite" doesn't appear in the output of [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) then support for it is not included in your php build, unfortunately.

Comment: @Asaph I actually think it is - I'm about to do some tests.

Comment: as for expense, digitalocean rents servers for $5 a month.  With $12 for a domain, that's about $72 a year.  It does mean managing your own server, though.

Comment: I see the advantage with using DigitalOcean, but I have no experience with running a server, @TadM.

Comment: They _run_ the server; you simply _use_ the server.  Cheaper _and_ they do the grunt work dealing with backups, crashes, outages, etc.

Comment: Okay, I'll think about that as a viable option, @RickJames.